# Are there any special tefilot that people say before/after someone gets engaged?

Tags: tefilla, engagement-shidduch

Are there any special segulos or tefilot that people say before/after someone gets engaged?

Comment: Are there any special segulos or tefilot that people say before/after someone gets engaged?

Comment: You should check with your rabbi before acting on any advice given in your case. (Mazel Tov, btw)

Comment: What do you mean by "engaged"? Often you hear that people plan on getting married well after they've decided to do so. Which moment are you referring to?Is there a reason you think that moment should be of halachic significance?

Comment: What I mean by engaged is afte the chasan proposes

Comment: What does propose mean? Like when they decide to get married? When the parents agree? When they're under the chuppah?  Is there a reason you think that moment should be of halachic significance?

Comment: Not that I know of but saying tehillim is always positive

Comment: @dude as is studying talmud

Comment: Studying Talmud isn't a prayer and thus not nogea to the question

Comment: @dude how is it less of a prayer than saying words of tanach?

Comment: "engaged" is a vague term, here. Among a number of Hassidic communities, esp., they do "tanna'im" months before the actual wedding. I'm uncertain if "tana'im" has the halachic status of what would be called "nissuin", and thus is a form of "reserving" the woman to the man. However, even if it is not that, the Tana'im has some form of "prayer" that wishes the parents of the groom and bride as well as groom and bride a form of blessing for the upcoming wedding.

Answer (score 1):

At any given moment you can turn to Hashem and ask from Him what you need, especially that which is beneficial for your spiritual growth.

There are some prayers composed by the Chidah that can be found on http://tora.ws. There is one for a [girl requesting a good match](http://mobile.tora.ws/index.html?bgf=lnn(224001,2,0)), [for a boy](http://mobile.tora.ws/index.html?bgf=lnn(224001,8,0)), or [for after an engagement that the Shidduch be successful](http://mobile.tora.ws/index.html?bgf=lnn(224001,3,0)).

Comment: You should consider adding in options for prayers on behalf of close family members if possible, as I suspect the OP would be interested in those.